# SSDs become unreliable when connected to usb3 ports

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, mac, ssd, usb-3

I have 2 different ssds and 2 different computers running 2 different versions of windows and MacOS X.

Edit: The drives are a LaCie Rugged SSD 120Gb and the original drive from the macbook put inside a transcend case that came with a JetDrive 725 upgrade.

Whenever I connect the ssds over USB3, they start behaving like they're dying - file transfers fail, vm's running from the drives hang, formatting the drives fail and the event log gets a steady stream of IO errors, NTFS structure corrupt etc.

When connected over USB2, everything seems to be fine. I thought it worked in MacOS for a while but just to make sure I made a secure erase from disk utility, and it also died over USB3 but worked over USB2

Normal spinning drives connected to USB3 work just fine, all day every day. It feels like the usb3 controller can't handle ssd speeds for more than a few minutes before it dies.

The machines are a macbook pro running windows 7 and macOS X yosemite, and a HP elitebook running windows 8.1. The only thing they have in common is that they have intel chipsets and run something identified as the "Intel extensible USB3 controller".

I have tried disabling power management on the usb device, and disabling and enabling write caching on the ssds. No difference whatsoever. Tried different cables and all ports on both machines.

If it was only one machine or OS I would blame the controller or the controller driver.

If it was only one drive I would blame the drive.

If none of the drives worked over usb2 I would blame both drives.

As it is, I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting these drives via USB? I mean, SATA and USB aren't compatible, you need some device inbetween.

Comment: I added info about the drives. I didn't think to mention it since they are different and have the same issue, but I suppose they could both be using the same sata-usb3 conversion chip.